# Setting the padding for an anchor based on parent div

Tags: html, css, padding

I've got a fairly complex html document that reuses the same dropdown anchor. The following code approximates the features I'm working with:

```
<div class ="btn-group dropdown dropdownTypeOne " data-toggle="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle btn buttonTypeOne">
    ....
    ....
<div class="btn-group dropdown dropdownTypeTwo " data-toggle="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle btn buttonTypeOne">
    ....
```

As shown above, the same anchor is used twice, once in each div. The CSS padding attribute for anchor, as I understand it, can't be inherited from the div above, yet I'm required to have no padding in the first anchor and 5% padding in the second. Is there a workaround to lack of inheritance that will allow me to set the padding for anchors based on the parent div?

Comment: Do you mean: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: This looks like a very handy trick! Is there a similar selector that allows you to declare attributes for all children?

Comment: Just choose a Fitting one: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

There are a variety of [CSS Selectors](http://w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) which help in such cases.